# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: Token "'" is invalid. while importing csv in pgadmin

Tags: json, database, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I have made a new table with three columns

```
customer_id,media_urls,survey_taste
```

in a db in pgadmin with attributes as

```
int,text[],jsonb
```

respectively.
I have a csv that I was trying to import into this table using pgadmin and
the contents of that file are like this

```
1,"{'http://example.com','http://example.com'}","{'taste':[1,2,3,4]}"
```

but I am getting this error

````
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: '...
COPY survey_taste, line 2, column survey_taste: "{'taste': [-0.19101654669350904, 0.08575981750112513, 0.07133783942655376, -0.10579014363010293, 0.0..." ```
````

Comment: It needs to be:`'{"http":"abc","http":"abc"}','{"taste":[1,2,3,4]}'`.

Comment: The database is right, that's not valid json. Search&Replace is your best friend.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver actually the problem seems to be in the ` "{'taste':[1,2,3,4]}" `
is it just because of the quotes?
because i made this csv from a dictionary and the quotes are automatically chosen to be in this way

Comment: @FrankHeikens can I use Search and Replace even before csv is loaded into the table?
and is it just the quotes that are making the json format invalid?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have tried it in this way now:
` 
12, '{"http://example.com","http://example.com"}','{"taste":[1,2,3,4]}' 
 `
and it now says 
 `
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
 `
I think that's because it considers taste another column...

Comment: My mistake I did not verify my work. See my answer for correction and a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To address your comments in reverse order. To have this entered in one field you would need to have it as:

`'[{"http":"abc","http":"abc"},{"taste":[1,2,3,4]}]'`

Per:

```
select '[{"http":"abc","http":"abc"},{"taste":[1,2,3,4]}]'::json;
                       json                        
---------------------------------------------------
 [{"http":"abc","http":"abc"},{"taste":[1,2,3,4]}]
```

As to the quoting issue:

When you pass a dict to csv you will get:

```
d = {"taste":[1,2,3,4]}
print(d)
{'taste': [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What you need is:

```
import json 
json.dumps(d)                                                                                                                                                              
'{"test": [1, 2, 3, 4]}'
```

Using `json.dumps` will turn the dict into a proper JSON string representation.

Putting it all together:

```
# Create list of dicts
l = [{'http': 'abc', 'http': 'abc'}, {'taste': [1,2,3,4]}]
# Create JSON string representattion
json.dumps(l)                                                                                                                                                             
'[{"http": "abc"}, {"taste": [1, 2, 3, 4]}]'
```